# How to turn off in-app sounds

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

How can I give the user the option to turn off all the sounds in my app - if they so choose.

I want the sounds to be there as standard. However, some users may prefer not to have the bleeps and sound effects etc in my app. For instance, in Camera plus or Paste Bot you have to option to turn off the sounds with a UI switch. How do I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define a variable to indicate this option,and save it in some place.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand that in context.  If I have a toggle switch for instance how can I code it to turn off all sounds?

Comment: @jonathan, was that supposed to be clever.  How is your answer to a question of how do I code it:  "by coding it" be of any merit. obviously Suggests I don't know how to code it.  Think!

Comment: Yes, but the answer is "if sound turned on, play sound, else don't". There's not really anything for us to explain past that.

Comment: I disagree,  if toggle is set on do nothing if toggle is off set a global variable to make sounds in my app to off. It's is the code to implement that I am unsure of which is why I posted a question hoping someone may "explain past that"